# How to extract JPEG encoding process with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, metadata, jpeg, lossless-compression

I have some images using different encoding types (JPEG Lossless and baseline JPEG), and I want to extract this information from my images.

I've tried a bunch of 'exif' parsers/readers but none works on my images because of the special JPEG Lossless (SOF 3).

I tried with some online tools (get-metadata dot com, etc...) and it works fine, that's what is outputted :

> **Encoding Process:** Lossless, Huffman coding

Or for a normal JPEG :

> **Encoding Process:** Baseline DCT, Huffman coding

Do you know an easy way or a library that could do it? I have the image as a buffer in NodeJS.

For information, this is the code I'm using right now, it's working - but I'm not sure it's reliable :

```
//0xFF 0xD8 means that it is a JPEG image
if (pixelData[0] === 0xFF && pixelData[1] === 0xD8) {

    //this field contains the encoding process
    //see https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000334.shtml
    //see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG for more info
    // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS ?
    const jpegProcess = pixelData[21];

    //0xC3 0xC7 0xCB 0xCF is for JPEG Lossless compression (SOF3)
    if (jpegProcess === 0xC3 || jpegProcess === 0xC7 || jpegProcess === 0xCB || jpegProcess === 0xCF) {
        ...decode image
    } //0xC0 0xC2 0xDB are baseline JPEG
    else {
        ...do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: How you though of using imagemagick?

Comment: It seems like a huge module for just getting the metadata

Comment: It's not a node_module. You install the cli for imagemagick and have nodejs write commands to the shell... for example: `exec('magick identify -verbose image.jpg')`

Comment: It doesn't seem to handle SOF3 images, also I'm working with docker containers and can't install too much programs

Answer (score 0):

You need a little more work in your code. You needs to skip over blocks with length fields. These can contain the raw value FF. Then you need to find a start of frame market and identify its type.

Comment: Could you provide some code or more guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: The requested URL /sourcecode/sourcecode/jpegdump.zip was not found on this server.

Comment: http://colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/jpegdump.zip bad copy and paste